# LocalDateTime precision issue rig my equals and hashCode methods

Tags: java, time, localdatetime

I have auditing fields as `LocalDateTime` type in my model.

I also use Lombok for `equals` and `hashCode` implementations.

Between persist (with ID) and fetch (by ID), precision is loosed.

---

I went ahead and truncated to seconds (then milliseconds) before marshalling and after unmarshalling the entity to and fro the persistent layer (DB driver)... But it seems there is more to it.

At the end, I implemented those methods in my base entities by hand (as opp. to using Lombok) and truncated `LocaDateTime` in there.

QUESTION: How to set `LocalDateTime` precision globally (system, spring-context or maybe else)?

Comment: What exactly is the goal? Is your database limited to a coarser resolution than the microseconds/nanoseconds of *java.time*?

Comment: The goal is to truncate LocalDateTime in a single place (to `SECONDS` for eg) so that I don't have to deal with differences in JVM across systems (Windows, UNIX, etc) and persistent layer (database) precision [loss].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `Clock`

You can optionally supply an alternate [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) to the *java.time* classes.

In your case, you want [`Clock.tickSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#tickSeconds(java.time.ZoneId)). To quote the Javadoc:

> Obtains a clock that returns the current instant ticking in whole seconds using the best available system clock.

For example, to capture the current moment as seen with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds truncated to whole seconds:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now( Clock.tickSeconds() ) ;
```

Comment: Oh, I see... Per instance. In my case, the date is set by a Spring's auditing bean wrapper.